# Android passing query parameter to viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have a view and viewmodel which has 2 functionalities -

1) Clicking a button in view and getting data.

2) A Spinner where you can select an item and ask the viewmodel to get data for that item as a query parameter.

I already implemented the first point like this -

MyView code -

```
viewModel.onGetDataClicked.observe(this, Observer {
    //....
})
```

My ViewModel code -

```
private val viewState = MyViewState()

    val onGetDataClicked =
        Transformations.map(dataDomain.getData(MyAction.GetDataAction)) {
            when (it) {
                ....
            }
        }
```

MyAction code -

```
sealed class MyAction : Action {
    object GetDataAction : MyAction()
}
```

My question is how do I pass the spinner value from view to the viewmodel? Since in viewmodel I have a `val onGetDataClicked` and not a function.

Comment: Change the val to a function and pass the id

Comment: Yeah but then I cant do viewState.copy(...) inside the when(it) {...} where I need to give the MyViewState back to the view. Could you pls give me a rough example. Would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should get the item value in the view itself, after that pass the item value to the required method in the ViewModel and from the ViewModel to the Repository(where you are querying the data from).

```
    // in view
    viewModel.onGetDataClicked(item:DataType).observe(this, Observer {
        //....
    })

    //in viewmodel
    private val viewState = MyViewState()

        val onGetDataClicked:(item:DataType) =
          Transformations.map(dataDomain.getData(MyAction.GetDataAction)) {

    //you have item here, pass it where you require
                when (it) {
                    ....
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the selectedItemPosition attribute from the view and pass position  to viewModel, accordingly you can map the item using the position.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data class="FeedbackBinding">

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.ec.service.ServiceViewModel" />
    </data>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/unitAET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:selectedItemPosition="@={vm.selectedUnitPosition}"
                app:entries="@{vm.unitNames}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

the selectedUnitPosition is a MutableLeveData

**fragment.kt**

In your fragment initialise the vm (viewModel)

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    withViewModel<ServiceViewModel>(factory) {
        binding.vm = this
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I pass it to viewmodel ? As a function parameter or how? Could you please show me a snippet?